# Is this path in Krakow, Poland drivable?

Tags: driving, poland, krakow

I will need to drive along a road in Krakow, Poland and one section is not obviously suitable for driving (but also does not look bad either):

[image]
*(map courtesy of Google)*

I followed [this road](https://www.google.com/maps/place/50%C2%B002'03.7%22N+19%C2%B055'15.5%22E/@50.0343624,19.9187823,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d50.0343589!4d19.920971?shorturl=1) and Google Street View for some reason [stops short of the inhabited area a bit ahead](https://www.google.com/maps/@50.0348525,19.9203107,3a,75y,320.52h,88.54t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sDUstv5DjAwhpp2EABOqkPA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) (maybe because there was a temporary no entry sign for the time of a construction). It seems that there is just a short connection between that point and the buildings.

**Is the section pointed above drivable? (with a standard car)**

Comment: I wouldn't actually call that a road.  It seems more like an extended lane/driveway :D

Answer (score 2):

I've seen quite a few such areas when bicycling in Eastern Europe and it looks to me as if it is a private, not publically accessible estate. That is confirmed by [the signage on the other side (where your 'to here' arrow is pointing)](https://www.google.com/maps/@50.0366155,19.9185064,3a,88.6y,147.76h,96.32t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1smDa96bPBrM-UwLZ0OW1dbA!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo1.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3DmDa96bPBrM-UwLZ0OW1dbA%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D166.03662%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656). The estate entry is secured with a gate (although open when the street view images were taken) and there is a dead-end sign with the text 'private area - no throughfare'. I would be surprised if you would not also run into a gate before approaching the estate from the other side, passing beyond where the Google Street-View footage ends.

It is in Eastern Europe not uncommon that upper-class housing is built in fenced-off estates, allowing access only to residents and genuine visitors. Both Google Maps and Open Street Map often fail to identify these estates as such and they are simply shown on the map as regular residential areas with seemingly accessible roads.

Comment: "Open Street Map often fail to identify these estates as such" note that OpenStreetMap typically identifies such roads correctly (see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:access ) but many maps build on OpenStreetMap data do not use this information

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny I was referring to the maps as they are rendered by the Open Street Map web site. It is IMHO completely irrelevant for the end user, that the low-level OSM database has capabilities to store such restrictions as metadata, when they are not shown on the rendered map.

Comment: *It is in Eastern Europe not uncommon…*, nor in Western Europe.  I've seen plenty of those in England.  And as for Openstreetmap, it's not *completely* irrelevant, for if access is private, any A to B route planning should avoid those roads.

Answer (score 2):

I can only advise you to try a different map. Google in general is not well-suited to judge the quality of minor ways. Openstreetmap has this area mapped in great detail: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/50.03489/19.91963

From this data: There is no road there, just a foot path. And there are several gates along the way.

Comment: But the Google street view clearly shows something that is *not* a footpath, and seems suitable for motorized traffic.  In fact the street view  shows a van driving *ahead* of the vehicle that captured the street view images!

Comment: There is no truck driving ahead - it's driving on the "street" part in the South end. The Google car then continued on something very narrow that is barely 2 meter wide. You can even see the "no exit" sign next to the truck, hidden in the bush: https://www.google.com/maps/@50.0341677,19.9212445,3a,15y,314.44h,87.83t/data=!3m9!1e1!3m7!1sfKtZiE3E-tLTz0X2i8m76Q!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!9m2!1b1!2i36

Comment: @PeterM It is likely that Google data is outdated here.

Answer (score 1):

The high-resolution imagery shows a lane for the entire path. Where the Street View ends, the sign on the right says 'Construction Site' 'No Trespassing'. It looks like the construction is done, so the lane probably does goes through now.

Comment: FWIW this seems to be a good overview, but I have no idea what current conditions are  https://www.google.com/maps/place/50°02'03.7%22N+19°55'15.5%22E/@50.0337486,19.9248203,274a,35y,287.22h,44.93t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d50.0343589!4d19.920971

Comment: Well, I have also looked at the satellite view but it does not show much, and as @PeterM said, the current conditions are the ones I would like to know (ideally be someone who lives there and knows that place)